# check if current time is between end and start time obj

Tags: python

I have data like this in a dictionary:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

data1 = {'setpoint': '366', 'Weekdays': 'True', 'Weekends': 'True', 'starttime': '10:40', 'endtime': '11:40'}
```

Is there a way that I can check if the current time (corrected for time zone) is in between `starttime` and `endtime` with a Boolean statement? I know these are strings, but would I convert these to epoch time?

```
data1["starttime"]
data1["endtime"]
```

I can print current time but how would I compare to a string object which are keys from the `data1` dictionary?

```
now = datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
print("Current Time =", current_time)
```

A date object isn't needed (only time) where if I do need to convert the string object to date, I would have to correct for Chicago time zone with something like this:

```
utc_time = datetime.utcnow()

tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')

utc_time = utc_time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)   
chicago_time = utc_time.astimezone(tz) 

current_block = chicago_time.replace(minute = (chicago_time.minute - chicago_time.minute % 15), second=0, microsecond=0)
current_block_no_tz = current_block.replace(tzinfo=None)
print("CHI-Time ",current_block_no_tz)
```

Any tips greatly appreciated... If you also had any tips on how to verify `starttime` is greater than `endtime` I would be interested in that too : )

Comment: If the date is ignored, how could a time *not* be between start & end time?

Comment: `data1['starttime'] <= current_time <= data1['endtime']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the times are always formatted with 2-digit hours, you can simply do string comparisons.

```
if data1['starttime'] <= data1['endtime']:
    # start and end on the same day
    between = data1['starttime'] <= current_time <= data1['endtime']
else:
    # time range crosses midnight
    between = current_time >= data1['starttime'] or current_time <= data1['endtime']
```